# Console.log on array returning array length but not the actual array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i am trying to dig into a lot more Vanilla JS and i set up an object and an empty array and i pushed the object inside the array but when i console.log my array it returns the length only. What am i doing wrong or how can i see what is inside the array?

This is my sample code

```js
let empty = []

let exp = {
  2: 'Hey',
  28: 'Yo',
  9: 'Heyyyy!!',
  6: 'Foo'
}

let newValue = empty.push(exp)
console.log(newValue)
```

Now if i do not use the newValue but do this instead it seems to work:-

```
let empty = []

let exp = {
   2: 'Hey',
   28: 'Yo',
   9: 'Heyyyy!!',
   6: 'Foo'
}

empty.push(exp)
console.log(empty)
```

Why does console.log(newValue) does not return the array and the object stored inside it? i thought that i should be able to assign values to a new variable. If someone can clear it, i sure will appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

push method add the value to array we are operating on and returns the new length of array.

```
let newValue = empty.push(exp)
```

is same as.

```
let newValue = empty.length ( length after pushing value )
```

second snippets shows the array as you're logging the actual array where as in first snippet `newValue` is same as length of array.

Comment: ohh!!! Thanks for clearing it up!! It makes sense now!! Accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are logging the return value of push, which is the length.  Check the docs for more [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in order to achieve a similar result to what you've attempted:

```js
let empty = [];

let exp = {
  2: "Hey",
  28: "Yo",
  9: "Heyyyy!!",
  6: "Foo",
};

let newValue = [...empty, exp];
console.log(newValue);
```